# Delay between creation and display of polygons

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon, dom-events

To create polygons in my map, I am using `jQuery.getJSON()` to load geojson files containing polygons and multipolygons. Then I analyse the geojson with a github plugin (loadgeojson) and finally the polygons are created on the map.

I put a `<div>` with a loading gif that overlays the map that appears just before the `jQuery.getJSON()` is being called.

The problem is the timing to remove it. I make the loading animation disappears when all the polygons **visible** property is set to **True**.

I want the `<div>` to disappears when the polygons appears on the map. But for the moment, it disappear a little before this. So on slower browser there is a relatively big delay between the `<div>` disappearing and the polygons appearing.

I tried to put a listener on an event but I couldn't find an event that corresponded to what I want.

How can I remove the loading animation right on time when the polygons appears on my map?

Here's my code:

```
function readJSON(id){
    showLoadingAnimation();

    // If .json hasn't been read
    if(stockArray[id].length == 0) {
        $.getJSON(id + ".json", function(data){
        showFeature(data, id)
        })
    }
}

function showFeature(geojson, elemtype){
    currentFeature_or_Features = new GeoJSON(geojson, elemtype, options);
    if (currentFeature_or_Features.type && currentFeature_or_Features.type == "Error"){
        return;
    }
    // Display object
    if (currentFeature_or_Features.length){
        for (var i = 0; i < currentFeature_or_Features.length; i++){
            if(currentFeature_or_Features[i].length){
                for(var j = 0; j < currentFeature_or_Features[i].length; j++){
                    // Display multipolygon
                    currentFeature_or_Features[i][j].setMap(map);
                    // Mouse events for multipolygons
                    mouseEventsMulti(i,j,elemtype);
                }
            }
            else{
                // Display polygons, polylines and points
                currentFeature_or_Features[i].setMap(map);
                // Mouse events for polygons, polylines and points
                mouseEventsSimple(i,elemtype)           
            }
        }
    } else {
        currentFeature_or_Features.setMap(map)
    }

    // Stop loading animation
    dontShowLoadingAnimation();
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like?  You might try using the idle event to detect when the polygons finish rendering.

Comment: I have updated my question to include the code. I've tried with the idle event. The idle event is called when the map is finished being loaded. But when I load the polygons the loading screen never disappears (the event is not called).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I modified my code to pan the map a tiny little bit after the polygons are created. Then it activate the idle listener that stops the loading animation.

It might not be the prettiest bit of code, but it works.

This is what I added to the showFeature function

```
center = map.getCenter();
latLngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat() + 0.0000001,center.lng() + 0.0000001);
map.panTo(latLngCenter);
```

And this is the Listener

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    // Stop loading animation
    dontShowLoadingAnimation();
});
```